# Cannot delete the key from java properties file

Tags: java, properties, outputstream

I read a properties file, delete a key from it with `remove()` and everything is fine until this step. But, when I try to use `store()` to save the properties into the file. It does not remove the key from properties file.

Here is my code:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
try (InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("/myFolder/myFile.properties"))){
    props.load(in);
}catch(NoSuchFileException e){
    // file not found, continue with empty Properties
}
props.remove("someKeyToDelete");

try (OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get("/myFolder/myFile.properties"), StandardOpenOption.CREATE)){
    props.store(out, null);
}
```

And this is inside myFile.properties:

```
someKeyToDelete=123
```

Also, If I run the code with this file:

```
key1.abc=abc
someKeyToDelete=123
key1.abc2=abc2
```

And I get this result !!:

```
key1.abc=abc
key1.abc2=abc2
123
key1.abc2=abc2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING` instead of `StandardOpenOption.CREATE`

From docs

> If the file already exists and it is opened for WRITE access, then its length is truncated to 0. This option is ignored if the file is opened only for READ access.

I changed it to `TRUNCATE_EXISTING`

```
    try (OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get("props2.properties"), StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING)) {
        props.store(out, null);
    }
```

it created properties file as expected

```
#Tue Nov 29 22:39:04 IST 2016
key1.abc=abc
key1.abc2=abc2
```

Tried it on Ubuntu + Java8,it worked

```
Linux ubuntu 3.19.0-25-generic #26~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 24 21:16:20 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Your solution solved the issue. But, I am thinking that maybe it is a bug.

Comment: @Arashsoft it works fine even if you don't specify any `StandardOpenOption` while reading/writing

Answer (score 2):

Just ran your code with your properties file. More specifically:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String ... args) throws Exception {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        try (InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("myFile.properties"))){
            props.load(in);
        }catch(NoSuchFileException e){
            // file not found, continue with empty Properties
        }
        props.remove("someKeyToDelete");

        try (OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get("myFile.properties"), StandardOpenOption.CREATE)){
            props.store(out, null);
        }
    }
}
```

... and it worked exactly as expected, with no problems.
Note: using Oracle JDK 8

edit: Maybe it's a file permission or concurrency issue. (I wasn't able to replicate the problem)

Comment: That is strange! I am using Oracle JDK8 too (in windows 10, 64 bit). changing my StandardOpenOption to `StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING`solved the issue for me.

Comment: This makes me think that it's file concurrency issue. If you have multiple threads writing to the same file, you can have problems like this.

Comment: I do not think so because I test it in a new project and new file path and I am facing same issue.